# Google script to return true if any cell has a background color other than white

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a script that sends out an email with a PDF attached of the sheet. The sheet has conditional formatting that changes the background color to something other than white. I would like to add to the body of the email if conditional formatting has changed the background color of any cell. How would I write the script to check if any cell has a background color other than white?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gets all non white cells on active sheet and displays them in a dialog with color, row and column

```
function getNonWhiteCells() {
  const ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh=ss.getActiveSheet();
  const bA=sh.getRange(1,1,sh.getMaxRows(),sh.getMaxColumns()).getBackgrounds();
  let f=[];
  bA.forEach((r,i)=>{
    r.forEach((c,j)=>{if(c!='#ffffff')f.push({color:c,row:i+1,col:j+1});});
  });
  //let html=''
  //f.forEach(c=>{html+=Utilities.formatString('<br />color:%s row: %s col: %s',c.color,c.row,c.col)});
  //SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html), 'Non White Cells')
  return (f.length>0);//boolean
}
```

Comment: very quick and precise answer. +1

Comment: It's a simple problem

Comment: Thanks for the help. One change needed is that I need it to just be a string so I can add it to the body. See the example below. `if (MailApp.getRemainingDailyQuota() > 0)
        GmailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, body, {
            htmlBody : body,
            attachments : [response]
        });`

Comment: I just thought about it some more and I just need it to be a var that equals true or false if there are any nonwhite cells.

Comment: Well you the just use `f.length>0`  and you can comment out all of the stuff for the dialog.